# Stripe Rails Cancel Subscription missing ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I think I have a problem in my routes or in my controller. I tried so much but I can't figure out how to fix this code.
It says in ActionController:

> No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"payments",
>   :order_id=>"sub_AzLXhqXdkvY0Z8"} missing required keys: [:id]

Dashboard show.html.erb

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>
  <%= link_to service_path(service), class: "panel-row" do %>
    <span class="panel-cell panel-highlight"><%= service.title %></span>
    <span class="panel-cell"><%= service.student.full_name %></span>

    #ActionController tells me here is my problem

    <span><%= button_to "Cancel Subscription",
    order_payment_path(service.orders.last.subscription), 
    :data => { :confirm => "Are you sure?" }, :method => :delete,
    class: "btn btn-danger" %></span>

    #

     <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The order_payment_path goes to the payment destroy controller

dashboard_controller.rb

```
def show
  @user = current_user
  if @user.profile_picture.nil?
    @user.profile_picture = "default.jpg"
  end
  @students = Student.all
  @orders = Order.all
  @order = Order.where(state: 'active') # gives me all the active orders
    @hash = @order.where(customer: @user.customer_id).map do |hash|
    hash.service #creates an array of service objects
  end
  @surveys = Survey.all

  if @user.admin == true
    @services = Service.all
  else
    @services = @hash
  end
end
```

PaymentsController.rb

```
before_action :set_active_order, only: [:destroy]
def destroy
  @user = current_user
  @subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(params[:subscription])
  @subscription.delete
  @order.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js do
      redirect_to dashboard_path, notice: "Successfully Deleted"
    end
    format.html do
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    end
  end
end

private

def set_active_order
  @order = Order.where(state: 'active').find(params[:order_id])
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users
resources :students

resources :services do
  resources :reviews, only: [ :index, :new, :create ]
end
resources :reviews, only: [ :show, :edit, :update, :destroy ]

resources :surveys, only: [ :new, :create, :index, :show, :destroy ]

resources :users

resources :orders, only: [:show, :create] do
  resources :payments, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end

get 'dashboard' => 'dashboards#show'

root to: 'pages#home'
```

Sorry if my code is messy because of the naming. I appreciate your effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is in this url helper
`order_payment_path(service.orders.last.subscription)`

Here you have two pass two arguments since it is nested path
the first argument will correspond to your `order object` and second will correspond to your payment object
something like this `order_payment_path(service.orders.last, service.orders.last.subscription)`

Comment: Thank you so much. This makes sense since its a nested path! Now i see it.  It worked with your approach when i changed the subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(params[:subscription]) to subscription = Stripe::Subscription.retrieve(params[:id])

Comment: @WenqingKevinMa - Glad to help you!